# Update column based on file views in document library

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, column

I have a document library with a bunch of files im sharing with others. I have a column called "Opened" which is based on a yes/no value, and it defaults to no for each file. I'm wondering how I can automatically update that column to "Yes" if a file has >0 views. This will allow me and users of my site to easily know if a file has already been reviewed or not.

Answer (score 0):

Per my research there is no related views property to be found in flow, and then update Yes/No column.

Comment: Here's a picture of the views property for a file https://imgur.com/dMCdPQo not sure if I am able to pull this value from anywhere in sharepoint?

Comment: Yes it's the view property, however we could not get the view property value in flow.